# Autotools - tar This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: tar, autotools, autoconf, automake

After running `make distcheck` I get the message that I have successfully built the package and is ready for distribution. If I untar the `tar.gz` with `tar -zxvf hello-0.2.tar.gz` it successfully extracts all of its contents. However, when I try to extract them in different machines I get:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The weird thing is that it was working before.

On the machine I'm trying to build the package, I've updated my `automake  1.10.1, autoconf  2.61, and tar  1.20 to automake  1.11.1, autoconf  2.65, and tar 1.23` and still the same issue.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Does this work: `gzip -d hello-0.2.tar.gz` followed by: `tar -xf hello-0.2.tar`

Comment: @SyggyF: It actually works. Any ideas why this way works and not the other?

Answer (score 17):

The problem is not on the build machine; the problem is on the target machines.

Not all versions of `tar` automatically recognize the decompression to apply to a compressed `tar` file.  Given that `gunzip` followed by `tar` does work, then the `tar` on your target machine is one such.  The versions of `tar` on the mainstream Unix systems (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris) do not recognize compressed tar files automatically.  Those on Linux and MacOS X do.

Note that you can use:

```
gzip -dc hello-0.2.tar.gz | tar -xf -
```

to avoid creating the intermediate uncompressed file.

Comment: 1. Is the hyphen in the end just a typo, or does it do something? 2. With this method I get the error `tar: Archive is compressed. Use -z option` `tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`. If I add `-z` it gives me `tar: -z: Cannot open: No such file or directory`.

Comment: (1) The hyphen at the end specifies that the input file is standard input (`-f -`).  (2) You might have a double-compressed file, though it's a bit unlikely.  You could try `gunzip hello-0.2.tar.gz` and then use `file hello-0.2.tar` to see what file type it thinks you've got.  Which version of `tar` are you using that recognizes that the archive is compressed but does not decompress it?  If you use `tar -xzf -`, you might be OK.  If you use `tar -xf -z`, then you're telling `tar` that the file to extract from is `-z`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this could happen when the server you download from applies another round of GZip and the client you used to download the file doesn't read/respect the HTTP `Content-Encoding` header and stores the HTTP payload as it was on the wire.

Although the file appears to have only the extension `.tar.gz` it is in fact `.tar.gz.gz`. after you run the `gunzip` once the file gets the extension `.tar` only but still this time running the tar command `tar xf hello-0.2.tar` recognizes the GZip format and implicitly runs the file through gunzip one more time before extracting.

You can check this by running `head hello-02.tar.gz` and `head hello-02.tar`. GZip is a very binary format, whereas tar is quite human readable. If the .tar file appears "too binary" you have a doubly encoded file on your hands.