# Input output redirection UNIX

Tags: unix, gzip, pipe, tar, cat

Say I have a file called `package.tar.gz`
Then I do: 
    `cat package.tar.gz | gzip -d | tar tvf -`
and it shows me the list of files in my tar archive.

However if I do:
    `gzip -d package.tar.gz | tar tvf -`
It says `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

I don't understand why that is. If the result of `gzip -d` in the first case returns output which can be interpreted as a tar archive, why won't it work in the second case?

I have seen [Autotools - tar This does not look like a tar archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331337/autotools-tar-this-does-not-look-like-a-tar-archive) but I'm not convinced that it's an issue with tar in my case since the first command works...

Comment: I think you're missing the cat part

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're not passing the `-d` option in the second case.  from the manpage,

> Compressed  files  can be restored to their original form using gzip
>   -d or gunzip or zcat.

What's probably most appropriate for that style is `zcat` which is just what it sounds like - gunzip + cat.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU `tar` will directly decompress the file:

```
tar -xf package.tar.gz
```

It automatically detects which decompressor to use (`gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, `lzip`, etc).

If your `tar` won't handle the decompressions, then `gzip -cd` decrypts to standard output:

```
gzip -cd package.tar.gz | tar -xf -
```

The `-c` option means read from standard input or write to standard output (in this case, write); the `-d` option means decrypt.  You could also use `gunzip -c` in place of `gzip -cd`.  This is 'standard' behaviour for compression programs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
gunzip -c package.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

Or

```
gzip -cd package.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

Comment: Oh, yes the second one works! Why do you use the < though? gzip -d package.tar.gz works just fine on its own but doesn't work combined with the pipe...

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

```
gzip -d package.tar.gz
```

will not output to standard out, which

```
tar tvf -
```

expects. The result of

```
gzip -d package.tar.gz
```

is that the file is unzipped as a side effect. Need to use

```
gzip -dc package.tar.gz | tar tvf -
```

to get the desired effect.